# selecting records in sql that have maximum value on one attribute which is less that another attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a table say `MyTable` with attributes as:

> Id (PK)
>
> patientId (int)
>
> Transfusion_Date (datetime)
>
> checkup_date (datetime)
>
> haemoglobin_level (float)

For each `checkup_date` there is a unique `haemoglobin_level`,
and a single `patientId` can have multiple `Transfusion_Date` as well as multiple `checkup_date`
(Here `checkup_date` means the date when the `haemoglobin_level` was measured)

I need to retrieve records such that i have the `haemoglobin_level`(s) of a particular `patientId` just prior to the `Transfusion_Date`

Please help me through the query that I have to write.

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far?

Comment: Do you want a single transfusion date for a single query, or a record for each valid transfusion date?

Comment: a record for each valid Transfusion_Date. If the Transfusion_Date is null then take the recent most haemoglobin_level reading

Answer (score 0):

This will give you one or more records for `myPatId` for a `checkup_date` which is just prior to the `myTransfusionDate` you specify.

```
SELECT checkup_date, haemoglobin_level
FROM MyTable
WHERE patientId = myPatId AND
    checkup_date = (
        SELECT TOP 1 checkup_date
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE patientId = myPatId AND checkup_date < myTransfusionDate
        ORDER BY checkup_date DESC
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
What is myPatId in your query?

Comment: @Abhi Do you want a record for each `patientid`'s each `tranfusionDate`? Or one record for each `patientId`?

Comment: A record for each patientid's each transfusionDate.
I want the haemoglobin level of a patient just before his transfussion 
and a patient can undergo multiple transfussions and multiple haemoglobin tests..

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @PatientId int;

declare @MyTable table (
    Id int primary key,
    patientId int,
    Transfusion_Date datetime,
    checkup_date datetime,
    haemoglobin_level float
);

select *
from @MyTable t
where t.patientId = @PatientId
    and t.checkup_date <= t.Transfusion_Date
    and not exists (
        select 0 from @MyTable t2
        where t2.patientId = t.patientId
            and t2.checkup_date between t.checkup_date and t.Transfusion_Date
    );
```